# How to convert base64 to RGBA8888

Tags: javascript, base64, buffer, arraybuffer, rgba

I'm trying to convert and image to base 64 and then to RGBA8888 to feed camera buffer, I'm stuck when trying to convert from base64 to rgba.

```js
function encodeImageFileAsURL(element) {
  var file = element.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onloadend = function() {
    console.log('RESULT', reader.result)
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

```html
<input type="file" onchange="encodeImageFileAsURL(this)" />
```

Comment: You're not converting an image to base64, you're encoding it as base64.  The image format (jpg, png, gif) is still whatever the image format was before you encoded it.

Comment: `    var binary_string = window.atob(reader.result);
    var len = binary_string.length;
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(len);
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        bytes[i] = binary_string.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    console.log(bytes.buffer);` Encode it to ArrayBuffer, would be the same to have in rgba?

Comment: The png format uses RGBA(8888?) color model I believe, see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_model) under RGBA8888, maybe you need to convert to png files?

Comment: I'm trying to get the RGBA from the png file because i need to pass to the function a image buffer in RGBA_8888 format, I dont have much experience with image manipulation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Canvas - I use canvas because it has ways to get at the underlying data, and ways to render any kind of image format onto itself.

Html image tag - not sure if this was necessary, but it provides an easy way to draw an image file onto a canvas.

I take the file from your reader code, insert it into an img, render that img onto a canvas, and then extract the raw RGBA frame from the canvas.  You can find out about the data format [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData) (data property).  I hope that is a suitable format for your application.

```js
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function encodeImageFileAsURL(element) {
  var file = element.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onloadend = function() {
    const img = document.createElement("img");
    img.onload = () => {
      const w = img.naturalWidth, h = img.naturalHeight;
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
      const imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, w, h);
      const arr = Uint8ClampedArray.from(imgData.data);
      // do something with arr
      console.log(`image width: ${w}, image height: ${h}, expected raw data size (w x h x 4): ${w * h * 4}, actual size: ${arr.length}`);
    };
    img.src = reader.result;
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

```html
<input type="file" onchange="encodeImageFileAsURL(this)" />
```

Comment: Thanks for providing this solution! The array buffer would be inside arr const, right? The class i'm using receives image buffers in rgba, should I pass 'arr' direct to it?

Comment: Yep `arr` has your buffer